# I am trying to retrieve rows equal to something within a particular column

Tags: r

Using R, I am trying to retrieve rows equal to `CS3013` from column `customer_id` within the data frame `retail_sorted` and assign it to a new variable named `retail_CS3013`

Comment: Please look into `filter` from `dplyr` package

Comment: use dput(head(df)) for reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if you want to have a new variable for the complete `data.frame`, or if you want a new variable in a data.frame with just the `retail_sorted$customer_id=="CS3013"`. Nevertheless, I leave you with a solution for the first scenario:

```
retail_sorted$retail_CS3013 <- ifelse(test = retail_sorted$customer_id=="CS3013", yes = T, no = F)
```

Then you can you use this new variable to filter the data.frame a show only the desired `retail_sorted$customer_id=="CS3013"`:

```
retail_sorted %>% dplyr::filter(retail_CS3013==T)
```